# I want to dynamically create instance of a class and use its method . Is there a way to implement using interfaces ? I need this in .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

I want to dynamically create instance of a class and use its method . Is there a way to implement using interfaces ? I need this in .net framework 4.5.

Suppose I pass a string which is the class name (inherited from the interface) and the object of the class would get created dynamically and I can use its properties and methods. Wanted to use interface so that I can restrict new methods getting added if any new class is added.

Thanks in advance

Tried going through the documentation of Reflection but of no use.

Comment: You actually described pretty much whats needed and whats actually all there in the language/framework. So what have you tried so far and with what aspect of it do you struggle with?

Comment: What is it you are really trying to do? What you are describing can be done with reflection, but using reflection is kind of the nuclear option. Sometimes needed, but best avoided unless you have exhausted all other possibilities. So what is the actual goal?

Comment: btw, .net 4.5 was retired in 2022; new development should not use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var type = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedTypeName);
var obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
obj.DoTheThing();
```

If you don't know what an assembly qualified name is:

```
var aqn = typeof(YourActualType).AssemblyQualifiedName;
Console.WriteLine(aqn);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to work with AQNs:

```cs
var type = typeof(SomeTypeInTheRightAssembly).Assembly.GetType(fullName);
var obj = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
obj.DoTheThing();
```

where `fullName` is `"Your.Namespace.Whatever.TheType"`

Comment: thanks this worked , I am just working on updating an existing application to make a specific class get executed via arguments